# Problem with second monitor (third screen) in Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, display, 22.04, external-monitor

I have a Lenovo ThinBook 14s IML with these specs:

[Ubuntu "About" section of my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18SoA.png)

For two years now, I've used with two other monitors, so I get three screens in total: the built-in screen of the Laptop, the second monitor I plug in using an HDMI-HDMI plug directly to the laptop's HDMI port, and a third monitor that I plug in using an HDMI-HDMI plug but through an adapter that goes to the USB-C port of the computer.

This has always worked great but suddenly, a few weeks ago, the monitor pluged using the USB-C adapter stopped working and is not even recognized by Ubuntu when I go to settings > displays.

I've tried other adaptors, monitors, and cables, and nothing that I plug through the USB-C port will be detected as a monitor, no matter what. This happened from one day to the other, I can't tell the reason.

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 with the hope that that would make the problem go away, but unluckily, nothing changed.

When I run

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I get

```
All the available drivers are already installed.
```

And when I run

```
xrandr
```

I get

```
    Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND7 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 600mm x 340mm
   

    1920x1080     59.96*+
       1440x1080     59.99  
       1400x1050     59.98  
       1280x1024     59.89  
       1280x960      59.94  
       1152x864      59.96  
       1024x768      59.92  
       800x600       59.86  
       640x480       59.38  
       320x240       59.52  
       1680x1050     59.95  
       1440x900      59.89  
       1280x800      59.81  
       720x480       59.71  
       640x400       59.95  
       320x200       58.96  
       1600x900      59.95  
       1368x768      59.88  
       1280x720      59.86  
       1024x576      59.90  
       864x486       59.92  
       720x400       59.55  
       640x350       59.77  
    XWAYLAND8 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 310mm x 170mm
       1920x1080     59.96*+
       1440x1080     59.99  
       1400x1050     59.98  
       1280x1024     59.89  
       1280x960      59.94  
       1152x864      59.96  
       1024x768      59.92  
       800x600       59.86  
       640x480       59.38  
       320x240       59.52  
       1680x1050     59.95  
       1440x900      59.89  
       1280x800      59.81  
       720x480       59.71  
       640x400       59.95  
       320x200       58.96  
       1600x900      59.95  
       1368x768      59.88  
       1280x720      59.86  
       1024x576      59.90  
       864x486       59.92  
       720x400       59.55  
       640x350       59.77
```

Finally, when I run

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

or

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

I get

```
*-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   logical name: /dev/fb0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
   configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
   resources: irq:145 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:2000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I don't understand the meaning of these outputs very well, but I saw people with similar problems sharing them, so I'm posting those in case they're useful.

Right now I can use any monitor If I plug it directly to the HDMI port, but I would love to add a second monitor via the USB-C port back again.

Note: When I plug the third monitor in through the USB-C port, the monitor transtions from a "No Image - Will turn off to save energy" state to a black screen, so I could say that it kind of "reacts" to being plugged, whereas Ubuntu doesn't react, it keeps showing just the first monitor and the built-in display.

**EDIT:**
I forgot to say that these two monitors, these HDMI cables and these adaptors are also being used in a Windows computer and on a Macbook Pro and they all work fine there.

Comment: Sounds like that port has gone bad.